# Batch TAB delimit also deletes characters T, A and B upon ECHO

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have about 300 files I need to parse which are tab delimited. The code I'm using below (not finished) is:

```
for /r C:\mywork2\MAX\ %%f in (*) do (
    for /f "delims=TAB" %%i in (%%f) do (
        for %%u in (%%i) do (
            ECHO %%u
        )
    )
    pause
)
```

It appears to work fine, except whenever a field begins with a T, A or B the ECHO removes this character? i.e., `Taxidea_taxus` becomes `axidea_taxus`. Is this a bug, or can I work around it? I should note that using `<TAB>` produces the same effect.

Comment: This is not a duplicate in my opinion because I am using literal TAB. This code is splitting BOTH tabs and T,A and B. Maybe I don't know enough about batch currently to get the most out of the subsequent answers. I'll experiment.

Comment: Because the TAB character as a delimiter works in this situation. I've already accomplished that. I want to know WHY it is also deleting T,A and B in addition to delimiting tabs. I don't think that question addresses this issue; if it does, I don't think I see the answer and could use some help.

Comment: It's deleting T,A,B because you have those characters listed as delimiters, and delimiters are removed when you split.  Is your intent to split on those letters (eg: `XXAYYBZZTWW -> "XX","YY","ZZ","WW"`), or to split on tabs?

Comment: Then why does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734726/windows-batch-for-command-tab-delimiter tell me to use a tab literal (TAB should be a tab literal). I do not want to split on letters, I only wish to split on tabs....for some reason the above code does both. I tried doing /F:ON but that did not work, and I'm not willing to attempt the 'hacked' response.

Comment: why do you think it "works" (does both)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `delims=TAB`, the processor uses, literally `T`, `A`, and `B` as delimiters. To use a Tab character, you have enter a literal tab (which will show as whitespace in the script).

Try this:

```
REM Set a variable to the <TAB> character.
REM Make sure you editor doesn't replace Tabs with spaces.
REM Enter an actual <tab> in the SET statement below.
SET "TabChar=    "

for /r C:\mywork2\MAX\ %%f in (*) do (
    REM Parse with the tab character.
    for /f "delims=%TabChar%" %%i in (%%f) do (
        for %%u in (%%i) do (
            ECHO %%u
        )
    )
    pause
)
```